# NSMutableArray resetting itself when WindowDidLoad is done

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmutablearray

When I pass a NSMutableArray from a controller class to a NSWindowController class using `@property` and `@synthesize` I am able to use the objects of the array in the `windowDidLoad` method. 
However, after the method is done and I click a button on the window triggerig an `IBAction`, the passed value is `nil`.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening and how I can preserve the NSMutableArray?

Here is the code:

**passClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class ResultWindowController;
@interface passClass : NSObject {
@private
    IBOutlet NSTextField *searchField;
    ResultWindowController *resultWindowController;

}
- (IBAction)passIt:(id)sender;
@end
```

**passClass.m**

```
#import "passClass.h"
#import "ResultWindowController.h"
@implementation passClass


- (IBAction)passIt:(id)sender {
    NSString *searchString = searchField.stringValue;
    NSMutableArray array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:searchString];
    [array addObject:searchString];  
    if(!resultWindowController) {
        resultWindowController = [[ResultWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ResultWindow"];
        resultWindowController.array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:array copyItems:YES];

        [resultWindowController showWindow:self];
    }


}
@end
```

**ResultWindowController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ResultWindowController : NSWindowController <NSTableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet NSTableView *resultView;
    NSMutableArray *resultList;
    //NSMutableArray *array;

}
- (IBAction)returnValue:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

**ResultWindowController.m**

```
#import "Results.h"
@interface ResultWindowController ()
@end

@implementation ResultWindowController
//@synthesize array;
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        resultList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i< [array count];i++)
    {
        Results *result = [[Results alloc]init];
        result.resultName = [self.array objectAtIndex:i];
        [resultList addObject:result];
        [resultView reloadData];
        NSLog (@"self.array: %@", self.array);
        // works fine, tableview gets populated, array is correct
    }
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)resultView{
    return [resultList count];
}
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)resultView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)resultColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    Results *result = [resultList objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *identifier = [resultColumn identifier];
    return [result valueForKey:identifier];
}

- (IBAction)selectedSeries:(id)sender {
    NSLog (@"self.array: %@", self.array); 
   //when I break here the array is nil
}
@end
```

Here is the NSLog result:

```
2013-12-26 10:36:49.487 MyProgram[545:303] self.array: (
    "test",
    "test"
)
2013-12-26 10:37:24.044 MyProgram[545:303] self.array: (null)
```

Comment: Put break point or nslog to debug it. and check its value when it becomes nil.

Comment: I did put a break point at the end of the windowDidLoad method, the NSMutableArray still exists. After that, no code is executed before I press the button. Here is where I put my next break point and the NSMutableArray is nil.

Comment: show us your button click method.

Comment: Well since I put the break point on the beginning of the method before any code is executed there is nothing to show. It is just a regular `(IBAction)Foo:(id)sender{...}`. My guess was that after the window is loaded the memory used by the WindowController gets freed. But I am not sure and also can not find any method to preserve it.

Comment: can you please insert your code.

Comment: please check following thing 1. Is array allocated, 2.it should not be allocated more than once, 3.is the array assigned to nil anywhere or released, all the above are followed and still not able to access array objects ..please paste your code (inaction method and windowDidLoad and windowwillLoad)

Comment: I did insert the code now

Comment: I included the NSLog, but it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `NSMutableArray *array;` from ResultWindowController class declaration and leave only the property declaration for it.
Or you could try initiating the array property in your ResultVWindowsContorller init class and in the `- (IBAction)passIt:(id)sender` just add objects to array.

Comment: tried both, does not change anything. I don't understand why when populating the tableView in the windowDidLoad method everything works just fine, the passed objects are correct and shown in the tableview. But whenever I press the button afterwards, they are gone...

Answer (score 0):

I honestly can't see how this works at all unless, in `-windowDidLoadNib` you are expecting `array` to be empty.

When you synthesise a property, [the default name of the instance variable that is used is prefixed by an underscore](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW6).  Thus the class in your code has two instance variables, `array` and `_array`.

There are several ways to fix this.  Here's what I think what you should do is delete the instance variable in your interface definition.  Then you'll start getting compilation errors every for each time you use it. Fix them by using the property instead, so for example, the line

```
result.resultName = [array objectAtIndex:i];
```

in `-windowDidLoadNib` becomes

```
result.resultName = [self.array objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: See that is what is driving me crazy, it does seem to receive the NSMutableArray just fine in the windowDidLoad method, using break points I am able to see all objects under self -> array, it is not empty. But whenever I press the button after the tableView has been populated with the passed values and widowDidLoad is done, the array under self shows 0x000000...

Comment: Also, i tried what you said, but it doesn't change anything, array is still correct in die windowDidLoad method, but nil when pressing the button